# Loading tiles while interacting for a single layer

Tags: openlayers

loadTilesWhileInteracting option applies to ol.Map. Is it possible to have that effect only apply to a selected layer?

Comment: How heavy is the task? Have you tried to load layers separately? Consider using fire-event rendercomplete then addLayer(). Or Set maxTilesLoading property to help improve performance

Comment: Currently using OL 4.2, so rendercomplete is not an option. This is a generic map client, so if there is a simple, "a couple of lines" way of doing this, I will go into it.